# What is the origin/meaning of "get off my cloud" and will it change?

Tags: meaning, etymology

What is the etymology of this phrase, and might the meaning change due to cloud storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase "Get off of my cloud" comes from the [Rolling Stones song of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_Off_of_My_Cloud).

Cloud Computing will not change the etymology of this phrase, because etymologies do not change; they are historical.

It is possible that a new meaning for "get off of my cloud" could be coined with regards to cloud computing, but the phrase is not automatically affected by the existence of new meaning of the word *cloud*.

Comment: Really? I thought it was what Verizon said to AT&T ...

Comment: Don't etymologies change in the sense that the histories of words continue to evolve? For example, couldn't you say the etymologies of _twit_ and _tweet_ have changed without implying their original meanings have changed?

Comment: @Callithumpian: I guess it depends on what you mean by "changing" an etymology. The word *tweet* meaning "to post a message on Twitter" has an etymology that includes the etymology of the word *tweet* meaning "bird sound", but the etymology of the word *tweet* meaning "bird sound" was not changed by the new word *tweet*.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: There are some counter-examples. *Gay* for example has almost entirely lost its former meaning of "lighthearted and carefree" and that listing in dictionaries exists now mainly to show what it meant in texts produced before, say, the 1960s.

Comment: @Robusto: I would regard that as a meaning that has become obsolete; the new meaning of *gay* did not go back in time and alter the etymology of "happy" *gay*, it just hastened its obsolescence. That etymology is still there. Most polysemous words have now-obsolete meanings, but the etymology of each meaning of the word remains the same. I would consider "changing" an etymology to be discovering new evidence that a word's origin or evolutionary path is different from originally thought.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Writing about bird-sound _tweet_ and message-on-Twitter _tweet_ as two separate words confuses me. Isn't it the same word, but in the process of becoming polysemous?

Comment: @Callithumpian: In terms of etymology and meaning, these two *tweets* would have separate sections and separate citations. While the original word *tweet* would be cited starting from the mid-19th century, the citations for Twitter-message *tweet* would begin in 2007 (or whichever year it was first coined). That is what I meant in my comment. Yes, *tweet* would be regarded as a polyseme. Whether you want to regard a polyseme as literally one "word", or the unification of polysemous words, depends on your theoretical framework.